# How can I fetch a list of objects through Restplus?

Tags: python, flask-restplus

I try to use `RESTplus` to fetch objects. My implementation follows the [`Restplus` tutorial](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshalling.html#nested-field). I managed to fetch a single object. However, I can not fetch a list with all objects.

This is a minimal implementation to reproduce the shortcoming:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields
from mongoengine import Document, connect
from mongoengine.fields import *

app = Flask(__name__)

connect()

api = Api(app)

user_model = api.model('user', {'name': fields.String})
user_model_list = api.model('User List', {'users':fields.List(fields.Nested(user_model))})


class User(Document):
    name = StringField()

@api.route('/Users')
class UserApi(Resource):
    @api.marshal_with(user_model_list)
    def get(self):
        return User.objects().all()

@api.route('/User')
class UserApi(Resource):
    @api.marshal_with(user_model)
    def get(self):
        return User.objects().first()

# Insert data into database
@app.before_first_request
def init():
    User(name='John').save()
    User(name='Sue').save()
    User(name='Li').save()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000
```

This is the output of `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/Users`

```
{
    "users": null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in my approach was that the MongoEngine returns a `mongoengine.queryset.queryset.QuerySet` ant not a list. After converting the QuerySet to a List, it worked even without `as_list=True` or `marshal_list_with()`.

```py
@api.route('/User')
class UserApi(Resource):
    @api.marshal_with(user_model)
    def get(self):
        return list(User.objects().first())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

Use parameter as_list:

```
@api.marshal_with(user_model, as_list=True)
```

or use decorator @marshal_list_with:

```
@api.marshal_list_with(user_model)
```

Here is the link to documentation:
https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/0.2/documenting.html#documenting-with-the-api-marshal-with-decorator